# Function to select pandas dataframe rows based on list of tuples of columns and cutoffs?

Tags: python, pandas

I´m trying to create a python function that takes 2 arguments: a pandas dataframe, and a list of tuples, where each tuple in the list have 3 elements, a column name, a min value and a max value. So each tuple represent a condition to be applied to a column in the dataframe. And then the function would return a sub data set for which all the conditions are true.

I have tried to create boolean conditions looping on each tuple on the list but then I couldn´t figure out how to make the function return a selection based on all the conditions being true, also because I couldn´t give appropriate names to each conditions since I'm looping on the tuples and could not change the names of the conditions on each pass of the loop.

I think I'm not approaching it in the correct way. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: `df[(df[col] >= min) & (df[col] <= max)]` Is this what you are trying to get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Dynamic Query function

Since you want to check for all the conditions, these will be AND. So we can start filtering them one by one.

```
import pandas as pd

def sub_df(dx,cuts):

    for cx in cuts:
        col = cx[0]
        minval = cx[1]
        maxval = cx[2]
        dx = dx[(dx[col] >= minval) & (dx[col] <= maxval)]

        #or you can also give it like this
        #
        #dx = dx[dx[col].between(minval, maxval)]  
        #   
    return dx


df = pd.DataFrame( {"A": [100, 200, 300, 400],"B": [10,20,30,40],
                    "C": [200, 400, 600, 800],"D": [20,40,60,80],
                    "E": [150, 300, 450, 600],"F": [15,30,45,60],
                    "G": [500, 600, 700, 800],"H": [50,60,70,80]})

print (df)

cutoffs = [('A',150, 350),('G',650, 750)]
df1 = sub_df(df,cutoffs)
print (df1)

cutoffs = [('B',10, 30),('C',50, 350),('F',10, 50)]
df1 = sub_df(df,cutoffs)
print (df1)

cutoffs = [('B',10, 30),('D',50, 100),('H',10, 50)]
df1 = sub_df(df,cutoffs)
print (df1)
```

Outputs for these are as follows:

Original DataFrame:

```
     A   B    C   D    E   F    G   H
0  100  10  200  20  150  15  500  50
1  200  20  400  40  300  30  600  60
2  300  30  600  60  450  45  700  70
3  400  40  800  80  600  60  800  80
```

Results for condition 1: `[('A',150, 350),('G',650, 750)]`

```
     A   B    C   D    E   F    G   H
2  300  30  600  60  450  45  700  70
```

Results for condition 2: `[('B',10, 30),('C',50, 350),('F',10, 50)]`

```
     A   B    C   D    E   F    G   H
0  100  10  200  20  150  15  500  50
```

Results for condition 3: `[('B',10, 30),('D',50, 100),('H',10, 50)]`

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H]
Index: []
```

## Prev Answer

I think you are looking for this:

```
import pandas as pd

def sub_df(dx,tup_vals):
    return dx[(dx[tup_vals[0]] >= tup_vals[1]) & (dx[tup_vals[0]] <= tup_vals[2])]
```

Here `dx` is the dataframe passed to the function
`tup_vals` will have `(colname,min,max)`

Example of usage of this function:

```
df = pd.DataFrame( {"A": [200, 400, 600, 800],"B": [10,20,30,40]})

print (df)

tups = ('A',300, 700)
df1 = sub_df(df,tups)
print (df1)
```

Output of this will be:

Original DF:

```
     A   B
0  200  10
1  400  20
2  600  30
3  800  40
```

Returned DF: (values in col A between 300 and 700)

```
     A   B
1  400  20
2  600  30
```

Comment: Hi, I want the function to work with a list of tuples such as the one you used.

Comment: Yes, that's how it works. You call the function with those. Do you want to send the tuple as an argument to the function?

Comment: I want to call the function with the list as an argument: something like, cutoffs = [('Price', 50000, 1e10), ('LArea', 0, 4000)] as a second argument.

Comment: Oh. You want to send a list as an argument to the function along with the dataframe? And you want the function to filter based on both conditions?

Comment: Yes, so to apply as many cutoffs conditions someone specify in the list to the columns in the dataframe.

Comment: So your condition will be dynamic in nature. You want to build a function that can have the dynamic nature of columns. Thats ok. It can be done.